# Security Camera in Server Room Recommendations

Tags: physical-security

Does anyone have experience with network cams used for security purposes?

I need to monitor a remote location (server room) from both the local network and the internet preferably.  I also need the ability to record-on-event (such as motion detection), run a process on event (such as email me), and capture stills.  Additionally I need an interface that will allow 2 or 3 users to view the feed simultaneously.

Are there other features that I havent thought of that would be desirable?  THe camera will be placed outside the doors of a small server closet in a building located an hour away.  Because I share this closet with staff in the building (who use it for storage), the doors do not lock.  On-site staff are unable to police the area, which is located in a building that is open to the public.  The closet contains a rack, some switches, router, DHCP server, and misc cables and spare hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good luck with the [Cisco WVC210](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9948/index.html).

Comment: very nice and feature-rich.  THanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  This really is a nice cam - exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Panasonic network cameras](http://www2.panasonic.com/consumer-electronics/shop/Computers-Networking/Network-Cameras.75091_11002_7000000000000005702) for this in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the input....I have Googled a billion of these things over the last few months and still havent made up my mind.  I havent looked at any Panasonics though, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have APC UPS' already you can integrate their Netbotz aquisition equipment.

See here:

http://www.apc.com/products/category.cfm?id=17&segmentID=6

Answer (score 1):

I use a lot of Rittal's [CMC](http://www.rittal.com/products/katalog.asp?ViewAt=5-1327&Dom=com&lang=GB&NavName=Security) rack kit, this is for very secure racks and detects motion, attack etc and has multiple web-cam support (as well as remote door opening too) but it would work for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The Mobotix Cameras are our dependable swiss army security knives. 
http://www.mobotix.com/region/index/

They have motion detection, picture sequences on alarm (pre and post), cyclic image saving to various servers, alarm inputs, switch outputs, call you on alarm to lists of phones, you can call into the cam to listen in (and talk), night vision, multiple alarm schedules, builtin webserver, secure wall or ceiling mounting, several power inputs, tampering alarms, and whatnot. Wonderfull piece of hardware! But oh, nasty interface. Still - immensely useful cameras with a range of good optics, some come with two optics for day and night.